# Incompatible pointer types initializing 'AVAssetReaderTrackOutput *__strong' with an expression of type 'AVAssetReaderOutput *'

Tags: ios, ios9, core-video

As I upgraded to Xcode 7, working code is now erroring out:

```
AVAssetReaderTrackOutput *output = [_assetReader.outputs objectAtIndex:0];
```

Isn't `AVAssetReaderTrackOutput` a subclass of `AVAssetReaderOutput` any more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the fix was explicitly casting the object to the subclass.

```
AVAssetReaderTrackOutput *output = (AVAssetReaderTrackOutput*)[_assetReader.outputs objectAtIndex:0];
```